# How to configure Thunderbird to connect to an IMAP email account

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I am trying to connect Thunderbird to a mail server using the IMAP protocol. When Thunderbird tries to connect, the authentication fails.

I am able to log in to the mail server with Firefox using the same username and password, and I have no issues.

How can I get Thunderbird to connect to the mail server?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SuperUser [tagged with Thunderbird and IMAP](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird+imap), those might help. What mail server are you trying to connect to? Some mail servers use non-standard SSL ports (Gmail, for example), so you might want to check to see if the mail server has any specific instructions for setting up IMAP.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your email server or your account has IMAP enabled.
Some email servers have it disabled by default.